# If “a group was hit as a group,” doesn’t it matter how many members were hit?

Tags: plural-forms

A team, which consists of A, B and C, fought with a dragon, but the dragon shot a fire ball to the team, so the team was damaged by the dragon as a group. In this case that the team was damaged as a group, it doesn’t matter how many members of the team were damaged? I mean, it doesn’t matter if only one of them was damaged.

Comment: Doesn't matter for what? I can't tell which is the sentence you're asking about, or what about it you think might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is this a problem? In the example you give, the team isn't damaged as a group.

If only one of them was damaged you might say.

> A was hit by a fireball.

Could you say "The team was damaged"? ... No "damage" to a team is understood to be damage to the relationships between the team members.  In fact the team might be stronger after the dragon attack. So, "no" the team was not damaged as a group.

"Damage" is not quite the right word, "injured" would be better.

Could you say "The team was attacked"? ...  Yes, if the dragon was attacking all of A, B and C, even if only A was injured.  No if the dragon was only attacking A and ignoring B and C.

Could you say "The team was injured"? ... No, injury is something that happens to individuals, not to teams.

Does it matter how many were injured?  ... Yes.  If only A was injured you would say "A was injured".  If two members were damaged you would say "Two members of the team were injured".  If all three were injured you would say "Everyone on the team was injured".

Comment: Actually, I’m really sorry to ask related questions over and over. But I’m afraid I’m wrong from subtle differences.

Comment: You are asking the wrong questions.... I mean you are not starting from a real problem and trying to solve it. But you are trying to create a situation that is hard to express.   Keep it real and you will find that there isn't really a problem for communication here. This isn't a subtle problem. If "A" was injured say "A was injured".  Don't say "The team was injured" and wonder if that could mean something other than "The team was injured"